# Extracting Revit files (Autodesk Forge Example):

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-data-management

I have completed the Autodesk Forge extracting Revit file example (https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/model.derivative-csharp-context.menu) 
but still have an issue.

To get the program to extract the file I have to

run > *click* extract > stop > Run(Again)

for the file to actually extract. I am just unsure as to why I have to run the program twice for the process to fully complete?

**Notes:** The windows notification shows as complete in the first run, but the file isn't created with the extracted data, it is only once the program is ran again I get the new file and a popup notification for it being created.

Comment: Assume no one knows that this Autodesk Forge ... example is. [Edit] the question and show a [mcve] and tell us what results you get.

Comment: I hit some issue with compiling this sample. I am upgrading my VS. While as far as I know, this sample demos a context menu of a Revit file. After clicking the context menu, the file will be uploaded to Forge, translated and extracted with the meta data. So I am a little bit confused on you will need to run a program with 'click extract'. Are you running Translator EXE only?

Comment: @XiaodongLiang the solution will only upload the file to forge if it is running, otherwise an error is sent "Unhandled Exception has occurred in your application"

Comment: @DJones, apology for my delay response. I can successfully run this sample. Yes, it requires to run the TranslationServer which performs the workflow, in order for uploading model, translating model, and extract metadata. It works well until the last step. An error pops out when parsing the json data. I am asking the author. However, I did not still get what you said  'run program twice'. May I understand you meant by 'clicking the context menu [extract properties] twice'?

Comment: @XiaodongLiang Once the example was complete, I need to run the translator server for the 'extract properties' option to work without just responding with an error. Instead of running the sample via Visual Studio then extracting the file, I have to run the sample, extract the properties then I receive a notification saying the file has been extracted, even though it hasn't. But if I stop debugging the code then debug one again, the extracted properties file is finally created. This is what I am referring to as run, stop then run again. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: Sorry, I am checking with my colleague, who is the author of the sample since I did not get the same behavior at my side. He will take time to diagnose.